# Narrowing through callbacks without overloading

Tags: typescript

I do have a function that takes a callback and a filter - based on the filter I'd like the callback to know its param types. It might be a bit hard to explain, so here's so come:

```
type Color = "red" | "blue" | "green";

interface Entity<TColor extends Color> {
  color: TColor;
}

interface RedEntity extends Entity<"red"> {
  isRed: true;
}

interface BlueEntity extends Entity<"blue"> {
  isBlue: true;
}

interface GreenEntity extends Entity<"green"> {
  isGreen: true;
}

// Last entity coming from a WebSocket or any other external source
declare function getLastEntity(): Entity<Color>;

function onMessage(color: Color, callback: (entity: Entity<Color>) => void) {
  const lastEntity = getLastEntity();
  if (lastEntity.color !== color) {
    return;
  }
  callback(lastEntity);
}

onMessage("red", (entity) => {
  // This shouldn't be possible due to our first param
  entity.color === "blue";
  // At this point I want TS to know that this is valid (again, due to the first param)
  entity.isRed();
});
```

I can achieve this with overloading - but is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want `onMessage` to be generic in the type of `color`, but you need to associate each color with its expected entity type first and not just the other way around (you know that `BlueEntity` is an `Entity<"blue">` but you don't know that an `Entity<"blue">` is a `BlueEntity`).  I've done this [here](https://tsplay.dev/mLyYaW).  Note that the check `lastEntity.color === color` is not going to convince the compiler that they are the same type, so you need a type guard function.  And `isRed` is a `boolean`, not a method, right?  Is that a typo?

Comment: Does the above approach [here](https://tsplay.dev/mLyYaW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining it.  If not, what am I missing?  Let me know.